# How to validate users inputs from indexes in an array React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a set of hard coded zip codes within an array.

I want to have it where if the users inputs  a zipcode and that zipcode matches any zipcode in the array then additional input fields appear in the form. if not they get a message showing "zipcodes do not match".

How would i properly validate a user input to match the data in an array? im using react.js

here is my array

```
const zipCode = 
[ 75013, 75002, 75252,75287,75035,75069,75070]

here is my function 
const correctZip = () =>{
if("" !== zipCode){
  return("Sorry we currently do not service your area at this time")
}
  }
```

here is my input field
im using antd for styling.

```
<Col span={4}  justify="center" align="left">
                <Form.Item label="Please enter your zip code" name="zip code">
                  </Input onChange={zipCode}>
                </Form.Item>
</Col>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to store your array valeus as strings, if you store them as num types it will trim off the 0's in zip codes with a leading 0.

but you can accomplish what you want with a simple loop.  For the sake of demo purposes I'm calling the user inputed zip "userInputedZip"

```
const correctZip = () =>{
  // loop through each element in your array
  for (i = 0; i < zipCode.length; i++) {
     const currentZip = zipCode[i]
     // if the user input equals one of the values in your array, return true
     if(userInputedZip === currentZip {
        return true;
     }
  }
  // if none of the zips match just return false
  return false;
}
```

as far as collecting the user input you might want to usestate.  Here's a resource from react on how to do that.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html